# Ruby array computation with grouping connected and not connected items

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I'm doing some date times computation where I have to calculate new hours group based on array of ordered date time hashes. For example, if this is initial array (I've simplified values but it's comparable):

```
[
  {first: 9,     last: 9.30},
  {first: 9.30,  last: 10},
  {first: 10,    last: 10.30},
  {first: 12.30, last: 13},
  {first: 14,    last: 14.30},
  {first: 14.30, last: 16.30},
  {first: 16.30, last: 18.30},
]
```

result should be

```
[
  {first: 9,     last: 10.30},
  {first: 12.30, last: 13},
  {first: 14,    last: 18.30}
]
```

It should also work with other cases when first/last one is not connected or when there are multiple groups.

My solution is with `each_cons(2)` where I'm checking groups per 2, but it doesn't work for some edge cases.

Thanks

Comment: Show your solution please, and an examples of edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your case where ranges are sorted by `first`:

```
new_ranges = ranges.each_with_object([]) do |range, new_ranges|
  if new_ranges.empty? || new_ranges.last[:last] < range[:first]
    new_ranges << range
  elsif new_ranges.last[:last] < range[:last]
    new_ranges.last[:last] = range[:last]
  end
end
```

Comment: Great solution ! Very elegant and works 100% for all cases so far :) Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

It'a a job for [**Enumerable#slice_when**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), array must be sorted.

```
array.slice_when { |a, b| a[:last] != b[:first] }.map{ |e| {first: e.first[:first], last: e.last[:last]} }
#=> [{:first=>9, :last=>10.3}, {:first=>12.3, :last=>13}, {:first=>14, :last=>18.3}]
```

---

[**Enumerable#chunk_while**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) does the same:

```
array.chunk_while { |a, b| a[:last] == b[:first] }
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you should add the `.map ...` clause from `slice_when` to the `chunk_while` solution.